# JavaScript e linguagem C acessando o mesmo banco

Tags: javascript, c, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou utilizando um app do Facebook (e JavaScript SDK) para utilizar o *login* em um site, além disso devo armazenar algumas informações básicas sobre o usuário. Por exigência do professor este site foi todo construído "usando a linguagem C" (Mongoose).

O problema é: consigo pegar os dados do usuário com JavaScript sem nenhuma dificuldade, mas o banco que vai armazenar isso está na aplicação em C (SQLite3).

Seria viável fazer com que a parte JavaScript da aplicação tenha acesso ao mesmo banco para gravar dados do usuário ou existe alguma forma de pegar estes dados e usar nas funções C já existentes?

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Tem como acessar o SQLite diretamente pelo JS, mas sinceramente eu não faria isto, ninguém faz, então não sabemos o quanto é confiável. Tem riscos demais e ganhos de menos.

Dependendo de como esta aplicação vai trabalhar é temerário fazer o acesso direto ao banco de dados. Vou considerar que ou vai rodar tudo no servidor ou tudo no cliente e não tenha dados sensíveis nele. Se houver interação entre cliente e servidor (onde estaria o banco de dados), aí o acesso direto seria temerário.

Já que existirá partes em JS e partes em C utilize o que cada um pode oferecer de melhor.

Como não há detalhes da aplicação não posso falar muito como cada parte irá se comunicar, mas certamente isto é possível de alguma forma.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Depois de ler as respostas que reccebi, decidi usar JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Em geral não é uma boa ideia permitir que o cliente acesse o banco de dados diretamente, já que um cliente malicioso pode mandar qualquer mensagem para o servidor. Por exemplo, um cliente poderia mandar um comando SQL para deletar uma tabela do seu banco ou fazer alguma outra malandragens.

A forma certa de abordar esse problema é responsabilizar o servidor pelo banco de dados. Se o cliente precisar fazer uma alteração no banco ele faz uma requisição HTTP para o servidor (possivelmente via AJAX) e o servidor manda um comando SQL apropriado pro banco.

E não se esqueça de verificar que a requisição do usuáŕio é válida! Isso é, se o usuário está logado, tem permissões para fazer o que quer, etc. Você nunca deve confiar cegamente em um dado ou mensagem proveniente do usuário.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Depois de ler as respostas que reccebi, decidi usar JSON.